# Using nested loops in Redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift, nested-loops

I am trying to create a nested for loop within a Redshift procedure but getting following error; **SQL Error [24000]: ERROR: opening multiple cursors from within the same client connection is not allowed.**

Question: What is the best way to get around it?

Example code:

```
    create or replace procedure test.nested_loop as $$
declare
  row RECORD;
 row2 RECORD;


begin
  for row in
select
    *
from
    (
    select
        col_name
    from
        tbl_name1
    )
        loop    
    execute 'some code';

        for row2 in
        select
            *
        from
            (
            select
                col_name2
            from
                tbl_name2
            )
            loop    
            execute 'some code';
        end loop;
end loop;
return;
end;

$$ language plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a single cursor with all the info you need.  This can be done by cross joining your tables.

```
create or replace procedure test.nested_loop as $$
declare
  row RECORD;

begin
  for row in
select
    *
from
    (
    select
        tbl_name1.col_name, tbl_name2.col_name2
    from tbl_name1
    cross join tbl_name2
    )
        loop    
    execute 'some code that parses row.col_name and row.col_name2';
end loop;
return;
end;

$$ language plpgsql;
```

If the number of loops in this code is large you will want to address this in a different way.  This process runs very slow as the number of rows being pulled from the cursor grows.

Comment: Hi Bill, Cross joining will return a relatively large table which is not ideal in my case. Is there an alternative way?

Comment: Basically I've got a table with 3 columns, tbl_name, col_name, data_type. In the first loop I want to go through just the table names. However if I bring in all the 3 columns, it'll unnecessarily loop through all the lines where it only needs to loop through 2 distinct names for example. In the second loop I want to loop through just the column names for the table which we are on in the first loop. If that makes sense?

Comment: You need to put the data you need to loop on in the cursor (single).  If you need distinct table names, then you a DISTINCT qualifier can be uses.  As for only columns for each of these distinct tables, this implies the need for a JOIN ON condition.  Write the SQL that will produce the rows you desire and loop on these.  You can test if the table name changes (remember an ORDER BY when loading the cursor) and perform table level actions at this point.  I don't know what you are doing in the loop but I hope there aren't many rows as looping on a cursor isn't going to be fast.

Comment: Hi @AIViz how did you resolve this issue? I have the same use case as yours, where I have table details in one table and column details in another. I need to loop through them.

Comment: Hi @just10minutes, I was able to resolve the issue on my end by making some changes to my code. Can you expand on your use case and I can help you. Thanks

Comment: My UseCase is similar to your's where I wanted to create DDL based on columns details. if possible can you please send a test email on just10minutes at gmail dot com